# Nombre de una palabra que comparte escritura y significado en dos lenguas

Tags: vocabulario-técnico, lingüística

Me gustaría saber, si es posible, el nombre con el cual nos podemos referir a las palabras que se escriben igual y tienen el mismo significado en dos lenguas.

Por ejemplo, "mano" (palabra española) y "mano" (palabra italiana) o "capa" (palabra española) y "capa" (palabra portuguesa) comparten escritura y significado.

Me suena mucho que dentro del ámbito de la lingüística había un adjetivo para describir lo anterior semejante a "homónimo", "homógrafo", "homófono", pero no puedo decirlo a ciencia cierta.

De forma más particular, me gustaría sustituir el texto entre corchetes en el siguiente fragmento por ese adjetivo que ando buscando u otra opción igualmente elegante.

"la palabra italiana "mano", de idéntico significado al de la palabra [que se escribe igual] española"

Si me pudieran ayudar, se lo agradecería un montón.

Answer (score 4):

### Cognados perfectos

> Los cognados verdaderos o cognados perfectos son aquellas palabras que se escriben de igual forma, o su pronunciación es similar o suenan de manera semejante en dos idiomas diferentes y que significan lo mismo. Un ejemplo de ellos es la palabra “chocolate” que se escribe igual tanto en español como en el inglés.

<sub>*Fuente: [english4kidsonline.com](https://english4kidsonline.com/cognados-y-falsos-cognados-en-ingles/#:%7E:text=Los%20cognados%20verdaderos%20o%20cognados%20perfectos%20son%20aquellas%20palabras%20que,y%20que%20significan%20lo%20mismo.)*</sub>

Comment: Muchas gracias por su respuesta. Le agradezco mucho la ayuda.

Comment: En un principio, y atendiendo a la definición proporcionada, quizá el término "cognado perfecto" podría encajar en lo que estoy buscando. Sin embargo, leyendo más información sobre este término, tengo la sensación de que "cognado perfecto" no es un término propio de la lingüística española, sino más bien de la inglesa, y que "cognado perfecto" es simplemente la traducción de "perfect cognate" empleada para explicar en español este aspecto del inglés.

Comment: A lo mejor me equivoco, dado mi conocimiento limitado en estos temas, y "cognado perfecto" es un término ampliamente utilizado también en la lingüística española, pero a juzgar por los resultados de Google, no sabría decir.

Comment: Por otra parte, respecto al fragmento de texto donde me gustaría aplicar el término, dando por válido "cognado perfecto", ¿sería natural decir "la palabra italiana "mano", de idéntico significado al del cognado perfecto español" o "la palabra italiana "mano", con cognado perfecto en español"?